# Is per-physical-machine synchronization possible in Java?

Tags: java, linux, concurrency, synchronization

I'm not an expert on it, but I know some (most?) operating systems have global, machine-wide synchronization primitives, so that multiple processes can coordinate concurrency.  My question is: is there any way to do this using Java? In other words, is there a way for multiple JVM's to manage their concurrency?

I'm interested in this because I have potentially several JVM's running on a machine, and I want to ensure that a particular action occurs only once per physical machine.

I imagine this could be done with, say, writing to files that can be read by all processes -- I'd love any insight on good ways to do that, or perhaps there are better ways to do it, accessing the underlying OS primitives, etc.  I should also mention I'm running on Linux and it's not necessary (for my use case) that this run on other OSes -- a Linux-specific solution would be fine.

Comment: Search for "linux interprocess synchronization" on your favorite search engine.

Comment: Thanks @AndyTurner, that looks like what I'd like to accomplish -- any idea how to do that with Java?  Accessing these directly requires C/C++ unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Why not move that logic into separate deployment that is deployed only one per machine?

Comment: Yes, @tsolakp that would work and is one option I'm considering.  However, for deployment simplicity I'd prefer to have everything contained in these worker processes (which are actually Spark executors).